# Building confusion matrix for image classification using SAGA?

Tags: saga, image-classification, confusion-matrix

I did a supervised classification of a Landsat image subset using my training data polygons.  I used SAGA GIS for that and everything worked out fine. Now I am stuck since I have no clue how to prepare the confusion matrix using my test polygons!

I know that I need for each polygon the number of pixels of the different classes, i.e. a cross tabulation.

How could one achieve that?

And yes, I know that there is this semi-automatic image classification plugin for QGIS and so forth, but I would like to understand the process of generating the confusion matrix itself from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Given the case that you are trying to measure the accuracy of a supervised classification, then generally you also have test samples, usually polygons. In SAGA, one has to convert these polyons into a grid with:

Module: **Grid - Gridding** -- **Shapes to grid**

After that, one can use that new grid in the zonal statistic tool found in the module:

**Spatial and Geostatistics - Grids** -- **Zonal Grid Statistics**

That leads to a table having (at least) three columns, where one (count UCU) holds the number of cells/pixels per test class and classified class. This table can then be turned into the classical confusion matrix, from which Kappa etc can be calculated.

Comment: +1 Great solution.  An interesting read regarding Kappa: `Pontius Jr, Robert Gilmore, and Marco Millones. "Death to Kappa: birth of quantity disagreement and allocation disagreement for accuracy assessment." International Journal of Remote Sensing 32.15 (2011): 4407-4429.`

Comment: Thx Aaron! Nice paper indeed. Hmm...how to program that in R...

Comment: This answer is outdated because SAGA 7.0.0 has two new toolboxes called "Confusion Matrix"  one for points/grids and another for grid/grid data. No need to make the Zonal Grid Statistics.